# Protractor test: is it possible to transfer sequential control from one browser to other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Trying to test one of our angular app scenario as follows:

1:Open the App
2:open context menu and click on an option which will open a web browser.(e.g click "help" from context menu and it opens new Chrome browser)
3:perform some actions on the browser
4:go back to the desktop app

Below is how my config file looks.

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['specs/Temporary-Dev-Pad.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        debuggerAddress: 'localHost:portNumber'
    }
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 700000,
    isVerbose: true
 }
};
```

Things I tried:

I tried to use

```
    multiCapabilities:[{
       browserName:chrome
       chromeOptions{}
     },{
       browserName:chrome}]
```

but it runs two chrome browser in parallel. For my scenario I need to run them sequentially.

Question:

How can I get the above scenario to run?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Does anyone have any inputs? Even little help to point me in the right direction would be great.